# Speeding up my KineticJS drawing canvas on mobile

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I looking to use KineticJS as drawing canvas and it works very on desktop browsers, but is very sluggish on mobile browsers. Right now I'm just continuously calling draw on the layer as the mouse is moving and setting the new points to the marker line.

What could I do to optimize the speed on this a little bit more without loosing the smoothness of drawing?

```
var stage;
var input;
var marker;
var points = [];

function initialize() {
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    });

    input = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(input);
    marker = new Kinetic.Line({
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 16,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
    });
    input.add(marker);

    stage.on('mousedown touchstart', handleMouseDown);
    stage.on('mouseup touchend', handleMouseUp);
}

function handleMouseDown() {
    points = [];
    stage.on('mousemove touchmove', handleMouseMove);
}

function handleMouseMove() {
    points.push(stage.getPointerPosition());
    marker.setAttr('points', points);
    input.draw();
}

function handleMouseUp() {
    stage.off('mousemove touchmove');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can improve performance by de-linking the draw's from the mousemoves.**

Since mousemove is being done often and repeatedly, just gather the points in handleMouseMove.

```
function handleMouseMove() {
    points.push(stage.getPointerPosition());
}
```

Then set up a timer loop to do the drawing as a batch.

Preferably use requestAnimationFrame but for some mobile you might have to use setTimeout

This will significantly reduce the number of expensive input.draw's required.

```
    // thank you Paul Irish for this RAF/setTimeout shim

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();

// draw the points in a batch when RAF fires 

function batchDraw() {
    marker.setAttr('points', points);
    input.draw();
    requestAnimFrame(batchDraw);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative but doesn't it eliminate the immediate and "smoothness of drawing"?

Comment: I hear you, my friend, but…I read the OP saying “Speeding up…”,  “very sluggish”,  “optimize the speed”.  This coding pattern will help with the need-for-speed by batching multiple expensive draws into 1 efficient draw.  This code does not do any line smoothing, but it does give the mobile CPU more time to listen for mousemoves. The mobile CPU can gather more data points and therefore produce a smoother result.  I do have code that smooths paths by splining through points, but my experience shows these spline calculations introduce their own performance problems on mobile.

Comment: I agree this would definitely save some processing power as calling handleMouseMove is rather taxing. One problem I see is that I'm aiming for mobile and Android has some notorious issues with setTimeout not working in a standard way on all devices.

Comment: I've been using CreateJS, which if I use this similar code setup works very smooth on mobile and desktop. I wonder what the difference on the back-end between the two is?

Comment: Under-the-hood, KineticJS checks for intersecting nodes when processing stage mousemove events.  That hit-testing, while often useful,  makes for a relatively slow handling of mousemoves.  Since you're just collecting dragpoints, you might try bypassing Kinetic mousemove event handling and listen to the browser's native mousemove instead.  Either way, you will benefit from de-linking draws from mousemove events.